# Stability requirement for time step size for this discrete non-linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

The system of differential equations below evolve smoothly in time, however, when numerically evaluating the discretized system one must choose an appropriate time step.  The required time step for stability depends on $\Delta$, the difference between the two boundary conditions: small values of $\Delta$ require small time steps. I would like to determine a relationship between the difference in the boundary conditions and the required time step.

Examining a linearized system indicates that the linearized system is stable for any size time step. This suggests that some non-linear analysis techniques are required.  Any suggestions about where and how to analyze this system?  Again the goal is to determine the maximum time step size $\Delta t$ which will allow the system to be integrated. (Note, this is not a homework problem.)

Below are the equations

$$ {dP_1\over dt} = k_1  \left(j_0 \,  Sign\left(P_0 -P_{1(t)} \right)\sqrt{\left \vert P_0 -P_{1(t)}\right \vert} - j_1 \,  Sign\left(P_{1 (t)} -P_{2(t)} \right)\sqrt{\left \vert P_{1(t)} -P_{2(t)} \right \vert }\right )$$

$$ {dP_2\over dt} = k_2\left(j_1 \, Sign\left(P_{1(t)} -P_{2(t)} \right)\ \sqrt{P_{1(t)} -P_{2(t)}} - j_2 \, Sign\left(P_{2(t)} -P_{3} \right)\sqrt{P_{2(t)} -P_{3}}\right )$$
with initial conditions
$$P_0=P_3 + \Delta$$
$$P_{1(0)}=P_{2(0)}=P_3$$

The discretized system is below.
$$P_1^{t+\Delta t} = P_1^{t} +  \Delta t \, k_1\left(j_0  \,  Sign\left(P_0 -P_1^t \right) \sqrt{ \left \vert P_0 -P_1^{t} \right \vert} - j_1 \, Sign\left(P_1^t -P_2^t \right) \sqrt{\left \vert P_1^{t} -P_2^{t} \right \vert }\right )$$

$$P_2^{t+\Delta t} = P_2^{t} + \Delta t \, k_2  \left(j_1 \, Sign\left(P_1^t -P_2^t \right) \sqrt{\left \vert P_1^t -P_2^{t} \right \vert} - j_2 \, Sign\left(P_2^t -P_3 \right)\sqrt{\left \vert P_2^{t} -P_3 \right \vert}\right )$$

---

### Mathematica code

Below is some code to demonstrate the topic at hand. Choose a small enough time step and the results are OK.  The question at hand is to estimate the required time step.

```
fStep[{ai_, aP1_, aP2_}] := Module[{bi, bP1, bP2, m0, m1, m2,
   \[CapitalDelta]t = 0.25 (1/2)^2, k1 = 2.5, k2 = 1, j0 = 23.3, 
   j1 = 23.3, j2 = 23.3, p0 = 152, p3 = 150 },
  (*note time step*)
  bi = ai + 1;
  (*compute flows given pressures*)
  m0 = Sign[p0 - aP1] j0 Sqrt[ Abs[p0 - aP1] ];
  m1 = Sign[aP1 - aP2] j1 Sqrt[ Abs[aP1 - aP2] ];
  m2 = Sign[aP2 - p3] j2 Sqrt[ Abs[aP2 - p3] ];
  (*compute pressures given flows*)
  bP1 = aP1 + \[CapitalDelta]t  k1 (m0 - m1);
  bP2 = aP2 + \[CapitalDelta]t k2 (m1 - m2);
  {bi, bP1, bP2}
  ]
r = NestList[fStep, {0, 150, 150}, 300];
Take[r, 10] // TableForm
Take[r, -10] // TableForm
vecP1 = Transpose[ {r[[All, 1]], r[[All, 2]]}];
vecP2 =  Transpose[ {r[[All, 1]], r[[All, 3]]}];
ListLinePlot[ {vecP1, vecP2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, All}]
```

Comment: To "use" the gray box, just insert four spaces before each line.

Comment: This seems to be the result of a sliding-mode design scheme. I recommend you to use some more familiar notations. Furthermore, in the sliding mode design it is better to use smooth functions such as $\arctan$ instead of $\text{sign}$ because the chattering could inherently lead to instability

Comment: yes, chattering is the issue here.  regarding the notation, the system is a pressure-flow solver, so P is the pressure at each node of the system. P0 and P3 are the boundary nodes and P1 and P2 are the interior nodes. The flows are from P0 to P1, P1 to P2, and P2 to P3. The flows are proportional to the square root of the pressure difference. Will run some tests with arctan rather than sign, thanks.